# Facebook App Link issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is implemented in AppDelegate

```
    #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
}
```

I have App Link with some parameters that is shared on Facebook. If my app is minimized, clicking link on Facebook opens my app and calling function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
        openURL:url
        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
        annotation:annotation
      ];
    }
```

like it should happened.

Problem is if my app is terminated (not minimized) clicking link on Facebook opens my app but function is not called so I can't process input params.

I have found something about handling cold start in Facebook documentation but that info is outdated.

Did I miss something to implement or it is Facebook bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented either `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, check that they return YES, otherwise it prevents `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` from being called.